# Eclipse dev tools for Nice

Tags: eclipse, nice-language

I'd like to evaluate Nice.

For reasons of familiarity of the development environment, I'd like to stick with Eclipse, so I would like to find something like JDT/CDT for Nice in Eclipse.  Anyone any idea whether and if so, where, that can be found ?

Answer (score 0):

From the Nice [wiki](http://nice.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/twiki/view/Dev/EclipsePlugin), there seems to be a plugin. No idea if it's any good or not.